# What do I have to pay attention to, when compatibility between Ruby 1.9 and 2.2 is necessary?

Tags: ruby

(Similar question already asked at [Ruby Forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6877419), but posting it here too with better wording, since I didn't get any response so far).

For a new Ruby project, I have the requirement to start the development using Ruby 1.9.3. I personally expect, however, that there will be a shift to Ruby 2.2.x sooner or later. Therefore, I would like to write my code in a way that it says upward compatible.

I was looking for some information, which puts together things, where Ruby *changes* its behaviour between the 1.9 and the 2.2 branch, but could not find any. I think I have to pay attention when processing files, because the way encoding is specified, might have changed. Also, I learned that 'each' (for Array) will have a different return value in 1.9 and 2.2. Is there anything else, which could bite me?

Comment: Here's from [reddit - Changes in Ruby 2.2, since 1.9?](https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/3elrzz/changes_in_ruby_22_since_19/).